# Manually Validating JWT tokens using middleware of .netCore 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp-net-core-spa-services

I need to validate JWT token using middleware of .netcore. I am not able to use inbuilt functionality of .net core to Validate token, since JWT tokens uses an asymmetric key, there is a restriction for sharing public key. I would like to implement this functionality in middleware. Could you please let me know,what are the steps needs to be followed? In particular, I would like to know what all things needs to be added to startup class ?

Thanks
Girish

Comment: "an asymmetric key", or "a symmetric key"? Might just be me but your question is a bit unclear especially given that you mention there is a restriction on sharing the key.

Comment: Hi Tom - It is an asymmetric key. They are not ready to share it.

Comment: If you don't have access to the public key, does that mean you have the private key? If not, what *do* you have?

Comment: You can't really validate a signature without the public key.  Also, take a look here, chances are this code would convert to .net core 2 (http://codingstill.com/2016/01/verify-jwt-token-signed-with-rs256-using-the-public-key/).

Comment: I have following items with me :Issuer(i.e., Authority), ClientID and ResourceURI(i.e.,Audience)  . Is it possible to validate JWT token with given configurations??

Comment: No, not at all. JWTs are signed typically with a key, which you will need in order to *verify* that the JWT is authentic. Otherwise, I could generate a JWT for you with those 3 properties you mentioned and you’d have no way to know it was me rather than your authentic issuer.

Comment: Oh ok. I get it .Thank you very much Kirk Larkin!!!. Let me check client team for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if you’re misunderstanding the JWT in Net Core? You create a token on your server using your key (keep that secret). The token is constructed and a SignatureKey is added to the end (part 3 of the 3 part token). This is used alongside your private key to determine the authenticity automatically for you. The only thing you need to share with the client is the token string itself. Net Core will automatically confirm its validity for you when its passed to your service. You dont need to share any keys at all